# count from 10 to 1 using angular

Tags: angular, count

I am working on angular project , In my code below is counting loop from 1 to 10 , but I want to make the count loop from 10 to 1 .

My code :

```
 TOTAL = 10; // total number of images
  currentIndex = 1;
  private interval;

play() {

  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(this.currentIndex)

    if (this.currentIndex + 1 > this.TOTAL) this.currentIndex =1;
    else this.currentIndex++
  }, 600)

  this.presentToast()
}

stop() {
  if (this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log(this.currentIndex);
  }
```

html

```
   <img src="index={{currentIndex}}&false=True&lat=33&lon=44" name="animation"
      class="img-fluid center-block" />
      <br>

      <ion-button (click)="play()">تشغيل</ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="stop()">ايقاف</ion-button>
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another variable for looping which is reverse than your currentIndex. Then use this variable to your html like below:

```
<img src="index={{reversedIndex}}&false=True&lat=33&lon=44" name="animation"
      class="img-fluid center-block" />
      <br>

      <ion-button (click)="play()">تشغيل</ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="stop()">ايقاف</ion-button>
```

Working Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-looping-reverse)

Comment: But why he counting from 10 to 0 ? can we set from 10 to 1 ?

Comment: yes you can. just change the condition to if (this.currentIndex+2 > this.TOTAL) this.currentIndex = 1; and I updated the code in the above link

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer() function from rxjs which emits after 1 seconds interval by the following code.

```
timer(0,1000)
```

As you want to reversely, you need to decrease the counter by 1 by mapping
and as you want to finish the counter when the value is 0, we use take(x) which take first x values and completes.

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-counter-10)

Comment: Thank you for answering . But i want numbers looping

Comment: Please make a bit clear what you mean by numbers looping

Comment: my project is animation satellite meteorological images i want to count number from 10 to 1 via looping number from 10 to 1 even i use currentIndex number like this  `<img src={{currentIndex}}.jpg" name="animation"
      class="img-fluid center-block" />`